# Setting Y origin for entire application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to do a very basic operation, but it doesn't seem to be working.   I have a BaseViewController that all of my UIViewControllers inherit.   In the viewDidLoad method of the BaseViewController I have the following code:

```
CGRect myFrame = self.view.frame;
myFrame.origin.y = 140;
[self.view setFrame:myFrame];
```

The code executes correctly, and I can see the new frame appears correctly, but for some reason not of the views Y axis are adjusted.   Any suggestions ?

My goal is to have every view in my application start at 140 on the Y Axis.

Comment: The view controller's view's frame will be reset after viewDidLoad is called. Explain your goal.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `[super viewDidLoad]` in `viewDidLoad` method of you inherited VCs

Comment: Updated with my goal.  I am calling [super viewdidLoad]